# Mode of ringing changes from vibration to ringing when Incoming call is from particular number

Tags: android, android-vibration

I want to create an android application that changes the mode to ringing from vibration when incoming call from particular number

Comment: For that you need Eclipse + android SDK and bit of Google search!!

Answer (score 0):

For Changing ringing from vibration on  incoming call use Use `TelephonyManager,AudioManager  and PhoneStateListener` as:

```
 TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 mTelephonyMgr.listen(new TeleListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
class TeleListener extends PhoneStateListener 
{
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
    {   
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        switch (state) 
        {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: 
                //CALL_STATE_IDLE;
               break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
               //CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
               break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: 
               //CALL_STATE_RINGING
               //CHECK YOUR PARTICULAR NUMBER HERE
               if(incomingNumber=="1234567890")
                 {
                    // USE AudioManager  for Settingringing from vibration
                    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);   

                    switch (am.getRingerMode()) {   
                        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:   
                            Log.i("MyApp","NORMAL mode");
                            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
                            break;   
                    }  

                 }
                 else
                 {
                       //DO SOMETHING HERE
                 }
               break;
            default:
               break;
         }
      }

    }
```

add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">` permission in manifest.xml

or How we Get Phone State using BroadcastReceiver see this tutorial:

[Get Phone State When Someone is calling using BroadcastReceiver Example](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127130519/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html)

Comment: i want to change the state to ringing for particular number not for all

Comment: ok @SupreetSinghSekhon then u just change back `RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE` to `RINGER_MODE_NORMAL` in `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE` means when phone is idle

Comment: i am getting runtine exception..."Unfortunately Application stops"

Comment: i am not able to find exception. When i am running the application its showing "Unfortunately application stopped"

Comment: ok when u have logcat stack-trace then post it but u are doing in right way just go with tutorial as is mention in my answer.thanks

Comment: The exception is :   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.audio.TeleListener cannot be cast to android.app.Activity